# Job Schduler install not working - sos-berlin software

Tags: java, mysql, scheduler, jobs

I'm going crazy trying to get this installed. I edited my xml config and installed mysql, java. For some reason nothing is being installed.

When i run the setup.sh script i get this:

```
./setup.sh -u jobscheduler_install.xml
java -Dizpack.mode=privileged -jar "./jobscheduler_linux-x64.jar" jobscheduler_install.xml
[ Starting automated installation ]
```

Nothing happens. It just goes back to a standard prompt and nothing is created. I have created the database and user in mysql. Java is installed:

```
java version "1.6.0_31"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.13.3) (6b31-1.13.3-1ubuntu1~0.12.04.2)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.25-b01, mixed mode).
```

My install xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<AutomatedInstallation langpack="eng">
<com.izforge.izpack.panels.UserInputPanel id="home">
<userInput/>
</com.izforge.izpack.panels.UserInputPanel>
<com.izforge.izpack.panels.UserInputPanel id="licences">
<userInput>
<entry key="licenceOptions" value="GPL"/>
</userInput>
</com.izforge.izpack.panels.UserInputPanel>
<com.izforge.izpack.panels.HTMLLicencePanel id="gpl_licence"/>
<com.izforge.izpack.panels.HTMLLicencePanel id="commercial_licence"/>
<com.izforge.izpack.panels.TargetPanel id="target">
<installpath>/opt/jobScheduler</installpath>
</com.izforge.izpack.panels.TargetPanel>
<com.izforge.izpack.panels.UserPathPanel id="userpath">
<UserPathPanelElement>/opt/jobScheduler/var</UserPathPanelElement>
</com.izforge.izpack.panels.UserPathPanel>
<com.izforge.izpack.panels.PacksPanel id="package">
<pack index="0" name="Job Scheduler" selected="true"/>
<pack index="1" name="Update Service" selected="false"/>
<pack index="2" name="Database Support" selected="true"/>
<pack index="3" name="Housekeeping Jobs" selected="true"/>
</com.izforge.izpack.panels.PacksPanel>
<com.izforge.izpack.panels.UserInputPanel id="network">
<userInput>
<entry key="jettyHTTPSPort" value="8443"/>
<entry key="schedulerPort" value="4444"/>
<entry key="jettyHTTPPort" value="44440"/>
<entry key="launchScheduler" value="yes"/>
<entry key="schedulerAllowedHost" value="0.0.0.0"/>
<entry key="schedulerHost" value="My_hostname"/>
<entry key="schedulerId" value="My_hostname_4444"/>
</userInput>
</com.izforge.izpack.panels.UserInputPanel>
<com.izforge.izpack.panels.UserInputPanel id="cluster">
<userInput>
<entry key="clusterOptions" value=""/>
</userInput>
</com.izforge.izpack.panels.UserInputPanel>
<com.izforge.izpack.panels.UserInputPanel id="smtp">
<userInput>
<entry key="mailFrom" value="scheduler@my_email.com"/>
<entry key="smtpAccount" value=""/>
<entry key="mailCc" value=""/>
<entry key="mailPort" value="25"/>
<entry key="mailTo" value="sysadmin@my_email.com"/>
<entry key="smtpPass" value=""/>
<entry key="mailServer" value="aspmx.l.google.com"/>
<entry key="mailBcc" value=""/>
</userInput>
</com.izforge.izpack.panels.UserInputPanel>
<com.izforge.izpack.panels.UserInputPanel id="email">
<userInput>
<entry key="mailOnError" value="yes"/>
<entry key="jobEvents" value="off"/>
<entry key="mailOnWarning" value="yes"/>
<entry key="mailOnSuccess" value="no"/>
</userInput>
</com.izforge.izpack.panels.UserInputPanel>
<com.izforge.izpack.panels.UserInputPanel id="update">
<userInput/>
</com.izforge.izpack.panels.UserInputPanel>
<com.izforge.izpack.panels.UserInputPanel id="database">
<userInput>
<entry key="databaseCreate" value="on"/>
<entry key="databaseDbms" value="mysql"/>
</userInput>
</com.izforge.izpack.panels.UserInputPanel>
<com.izforge.izpack.panels.UserInputPanel id="dbconnection">
<userInput>
<entry key="databaseHost" value="my_hostname"/>
<entry key="databasePassword" value="my_password"/>
<entry key="databaseUser" value="scheduler"/>
<entry key="databaseSchema" value="jobScheduler"/>
<entry key="connectorMaria" value="yes"/>
<entry key="databasePort" value="my_port"/>
</userInput>
</com.izforge.izpack.panels.UserInputPanel>
<com.izforge.izpack.panels.UserInputPanel id="jdbc">
<userInput/>
</com.izforge.izpack.panels.UserInputPanel>
<com.izforge.izpack.panels.UserInputPanel id="cron">
<userInput/>
</com.izforge.izpack.panels.UserInputPanel>
<com.izforge.izpack.panels.InstallPanel id="install"/>
<com.izforge.izpack.panels.ProcessPanel id="process"/>
<com.izforge.izpack.panels.FinishPanel id="finish"/>
</AutomatedInstallation>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem turned out to be java. I had to reinstall java and use java 7. Something must have gotten messed up during my initial install of java.